# How to save selected radio button value in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in `MVC4`.In this I am using the following code for `radio buttons` :

**Model :**

```
 public class PlatInspHistoryModels
 {
  public List<RadioButtonItem> RadioButtonList { get; set; }
  public string SelectedRadioButton { get; set; }
}

public class RadioButtonItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
}
```

**controller :**

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new PlatInspHistoryModels
        {
            RadioButtonList = new List<RadioButtonItem>
                                                      {
                                                          new RadioButtonItem
                                                              {
                                                                  Name = "Topside", Value = "T",Selected = true,Visible = true
                                                              },
                                                          new RadioButtonItem
                                                              {
                                                                  Name="Underwater", Value = "U",Selected = false,Visible = true
                                                              }
                                                      }
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

**View :**

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "PlatInspHistory", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
     {
    <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        foreach (Cairs2.Models.RadioButtonItem item in Model.RadioButtonList)
                        {
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Name)
                            @Html.RadioButton("PlatInspHistoryModels.SelectedRadioButton", item.Value, item.Selected, new { @class = "formCheckbox", tabindex = "1" })    
                        }


                    </td>
  </tr>
            </table>
  }
```

**Problem :**

From the above code I am able to bind radio buttons as a list. But how I can get selected radio value on `save event` given below :

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(PlatInspHistoryModels model)
    {
  }
```

Comment: In your `ActionResult Index` you will receive  only value of selected radio, not list.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `foreach` loop with this with a `for` loop and use strongly typed helpers:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.RadioButtonList.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.RadioButtonList[i].Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RadioButtonList[i].Name)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedRadioButton, Model.RadioButtonList[i].Value, new { @class = "formCheckbox", tabindex = "1" })    
}
```

Comment: Ohh I had removed the second form now.But @Darin how i will get selected value on save ?

Comment: What is the use of for loop here ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. The RadioButton should be bound to the `SelectedRadioButton` property on the model. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am working in MVC5, i have mcqs questions in the form of radio buttons that are randomly fetched from database   here is my`[Table("Mcqs")]

```
public class MCQS   
      {         [Key]     
        public int Qid { get; set; }  
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Skill.")]     
        public string Skill { get; set; }      
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Question.")]     
        public string Question { get; set; }      
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Level.")]    
        public string Levels { get; set; }     
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Options.")]   
       public string AnsOpt1 { get; set; }   
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Options.")]    
      public string AnsOpt2 { get; set; }       
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Options.")]    
       public string AnsOpt3 { get; set; }       
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Options.")]   
      public string AnsOpt4 { get; set; }      
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Set Weightage.")]
```

and controller

```
  public ActionResult Index()     
 {             return View((from a in ne.Mcqs orderby Guid.NewGuid() select a).Take(2).ToList());          }
```

and view

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)   
{<tr>           
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.Qid)</td>       
  <td>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Question)</td> <td>           
      @Html.RadioButton("skillsq1", new { id = "1"}).   
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnsOpt1)</td><td>          
   @Html.RadioButton("skillsq1", new { id = "2"})   
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnsOpt2) </td><td>       
  @Html.RadioButton("skillsq1", new { id = "3" })   
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnsOpt3) </td> <td>     

@Html.RadioButton("skillsq1", new { id = "4" }) 
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AnsOpt4) </td> </tr>}
```

i want to ask that how i get the  value of the checked radio button of the shuffled question